# Using Groovy's !=~ matcher

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a string such as

```
def cmdPieces = "config +D BARG1 WORDS=FULLY END=M"
```

that I'm trying to match against a pattern such as this:

```
if ((cmdPieces.any() { it ==~ /=/ }) & (cmdPieces.any() { it !=~ /\+|\-/ }))
```

so that if there are ONLY `=` signs in the string, it will evaluate one way, and if there are a combination of `+` and/or `-` anywhere in the string, it will evaluate yet another way.

I have a feeling my matcher is not working correctly.

Can someone correct this complex matcher so that it will work correctly?  Sorry for the confusion, it's difficult to boil this down to the essence, but I think I've done it correctly.

Comment: Please give some example strings and what/how they are supposed to be matched.

Comment: for such a simple case, isn't it easier to just use the String.contains method?

Comment: still working on this, nothing works so far for me...

Comment: oops, didn't finish my comment!  `if ((cmdPieces.contains('+')) & (cmdPieces.contains('-')) & (!cmdPieces.contains('='))) {`   gives exception  Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.contains() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [+]

Comment: @user2109043 That means `cmdPieces` is an array of Strings, and so your question above is wrong and misleading

Comment: so tim_yates, if you create a section for "wrong and misleading" questions, go ahead and move my question there.

Comment: fact is, I'm struggling through reading all I can get my hands on, and researching as much as I can, and trying to work through a real example.  And newsflash... I'm not a developer by trade.  So say what you will, but I'm having fun doing this, and I'm not trying to be wrong or misleading... only uninformed and un-trained.

Answer (score -1):

looks like this works...

`if (((cmdPieces.toString().contains("+")) || (cmdPieces.toString().contains("-"))) & (!cmdPieces.toString().contains('=')))`